# Creating a Dialogue tree

Tags: c++, tree, sdl, game-engine, dialog

So, I'm working on a simple project in SDL2 at the moment, and I'm having a tough time getting my head around code for a dialogue tree. I've pretty much got everything done except for this. So let's start with what a dialogue tree is:
[image: An example dialogue tree I got off google]

So, a dialogue tree is basically a branching story that the user is able to respond to and influence the questions asked to get a different outcome. This is becoming increasingly popular in games.

Next I'll explain what I've done. I'll do this by showing you an extract of my code:

```
switch(faze){
case 1:
    if(button1Press){
        button1Press = false;
        textToAdd += "That's nice, I'm glad to hear it.\n";
        answer1TextToAdd = "As am I";
        answer2TextToAdd = "How are you holding up?";
        answer3TextToAdd = "Wassup with you?";
    }else if(button2Press){
        button2Press = false;
        textToAdd += "What do you mean Meh?\n";
        answer1TextToAdd = "Meh";
        answer2TextToAdd = "Just; Meh...";
        answer3TextToAdd = "I've been up and down recently.";
    }else if(button3Press){
        button3Press = false;
        textToAdd += "I'm sorry, you wanna talk about it?.\n";
        answer1TextToAdd = "No, I'm fine.";
        answer2TextToAdd = "I'll live";
        answer3TextToAdd = "Yeah...";
    }
break;
case 2:
    if(button1Press){
        button1Press = false;
        textToAdd += "Cool.\n";
        answer1TextToAdd = "I am.";
        answer2TextToAdd = "Totally.";
        answer3TextToAdd = "Yup.";
    }else if(button2Press){
        button2Press = false;
        textToAdd += "Wow.\n";
        answer1TextToAdd = ":S";
        answer2TextToAdd = "Yup.";
        answer3TextToAdd = "I know.";
    }else if(button3Press){
        button3Press = false;
        textToAdd += "Go on...\n";
        answer1TextToAdd = "It doesn't matter.";
        answer2TextToAdd = "I'm fine";
        answer3TextToAdd = "Yeah...";
    }
break;
```

So, let me explain this; faze is the variable which defines what point  at the game we're at, this is incremented when one of the buttons are pressed, the "TextToAdd" is unimportant, but answer 1, answer 2 and answer 3 are the 3 possible answers the user can give.

As you can see, it only responds to button presses, what the user said is unimportant, the response is purely based on which button. This results in the dialogue tree looking more like this:
[image: My diagram]

As you can see, it ignores the question asked, and even the answer. The only thing my engine has to go on is which button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually organize it more "complex".

Every step in the dialog should have a pointer to the next, so you can
choose, wich part of the dialog is the next.
This makes everything easier, you can even go back in your tree.

So the Dialogpart class holds:
*pointer to the next part
*aviable choices
*func to choose
*func to draw buttons for choices

Implementations like you did are okay for a small application, but horrible for
bigger games or actually longer dialoges.

Comment: I actually realized the solution as I posted the question, but I wondered if anyone would have a better solution.